# List of installed packages on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: server

I need to know, what are installed packages for Ubuntu Server for the first time?

I need the output of `dpkg -l` of freshly installed 32-bit ubuntu-server (just openssh server, without mail, file, web server packages)

I need the list of installed packages so I could uninstall/clean up packages that not installed by default on my computer (without reinstalling the ubuntu) that was installed by my friend.

Comment: @Ashish I don't think this is a duplicate of your referenced Q. I think the OP is asking for upfront information.

Comment: @ClassStacker Actually I think it is a duplicate :) If you follow the links Oli provided (they are outdated, so you have to tweak the url a bit), you will find the manifet file that contains default packages list for your Ubuntu version. i.e. for Ubuntu desktop : http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.manifest

Comment: but there are no manifest file for ubuntu-server

Comment: No manifest but a file [listing](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.list) is available

Comment: Found [this](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/unpacked/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386.manifest). I don't know wether there's a real difference between ubuntu server and server-cloudimg

Comment: umm, it seems server-cloudimg contains more `http://www.diffchecker.com/uvsfi2g1`